# Rails 4 + Turbolinks: JS in the head or at the bottom of the body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm used to sticking my JS at the bottom of my body element (as per HTML5Boilerplate), but since [TurboLinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), which will be [on by default](https://twitter.com/dhh/status/251024691337244672) in Rails 4, reloads the body (and title) on every request, would it make sense to put my JS in the head from now on? Are there any decent guides or best practices on this yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also precompiled application.js (as per the assets pipeline) is on and in head by default. The reasoning is that even if the js is loaded before the rest of the page, as the js is always the same it will be loaded from cache from the second request onwards, so there is no actual reason to serve it at the bottom of the body anymore.

Comment: it caches the file, but it still need to wait for the js to load (if the whole page is loaded), doesn't it? Wouldn't an `async` attribute provide the benefits of adding to the bottom without being reloaded by Turbolinks?

Comment: With the normal rails sprocket-based assets, you will have a compressed, minified js that's usually stored in the browser's cache. Load time (as in "load the code") is anyway a fraction of the total download+wait+load time for js.
In any case, TL simply loads the whole page in background, then takes the elements (title, body etc) and swaps them into your page instead of the current ones. It's a simple behavior, which may or may not result in greater speed. In real world examples, I found sprockets compiled javascript in head more than enough.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Turbolinks 5, you can now put turbolinks at the bottom of your body (and follow web dev best practices for rendering a page). This also helps with SEO ever so slightly. Simply add your scripts to the bottom of your body and add

`data-turbolinks-eval="false"`

to your script tag. This will prevent turbolinks from evaluating *after* the initial page load. Here's how it is done with the `javascript_include_tag`:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => 'false'%>`

Then just use

`$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    // code to be executed when use changes pages
});`